# Animate NSLayoutConstraint & view simultaneously in separate blocks

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have two relatively simple animations. One is animating the top constraint of a `UIButton` so that it slides up. The other is animating the background color on a `UIView`.

```
self.buttonAnimationConstant.constant = 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // ensure the constraint is at 0
self.buttonAnimationConstraint.constant = 100
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

and my color animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0) {
    self.colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
}
```

If I try executing them at the same time, then the button will animate up but it cancels the color animation, presumably because of `view.layoutIfNeeded`. Note that these two animations are in separate places so they can't be joined into one block (one sits at the view controller level, the other embedded inside a custom view but both within the same view controller). How can I animate both a constraint and a view property such that one doesn't cancel the other?

Essentially the issue is how do you go about animating both a constraint and a view that sit in the same view hierarchy?

Comment: Like @Jelly, I have created a small sample app and cannot reproduce your problem. My sample app has one button. When pressed, the view will animate the button's top constraint to move the button and will change the background color of the view. The background color animation is registered first, then `view.layoutIfNeeded()` is called, then the animation to move the button is registered.

Comment: Then it's probably some side-effect I'm not seeing. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation blocks do not cancel each other. The issue here is this line:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // ensure the constraint is at 0
```

Calling `layoutIfNeeded` outside an animation block will cancel your animations (because they set a new value for the values you animate) and there is not much you can do to prevent that. What you could do is making sure that no `layoutIfNeeded` is called outside an animation block while performing an animation. Of course this does not happen if the views are not in the same view hierarchy.

Comment: Originally I wasn't using `view.layoutIfNeeded` outside the animation block and the issue still occurs.

Comment: In that case the issue might be in some other place. Are you sure that `layoutIfNeeded` doesn't trigger other code that changes the color?

Comment: Not that I know of. `layoutIfNeeded` is only called within the constraint animation block. :shrug:

Comment: Well I just created a sample project to reproduce your issue and it works fine for me. There is some other problem with your code.

Comment: My guess is that your `backgroundColor` is set from some other place. You could override it to check that. Or someone explicitly cancelling the animation, but this is unlikely.